# How can I determine whether a value is empty?

Tags: html, django, jinja2

I want to avoid displaying URL if the id field is empty in the Jinja template.

Right now it looks like below where it works fine

```
{% for some_url in item.some_url %}
    <td scope="row">
        <a href="{% url 'any_view' %}?id={{some_url}}">Click Here</a>
    </td>
 {% endfor %}
```

I've tried a couple of ways to find if some_url is empty or not but haven't succeeded yet. Recently I tried the following code:

```
{% for some_url in item.some_url %}
    <td scope="row">
        <a href="{% url 'any_view' %}?id={{some_url}}">Click Here</a>
        {% if item.some_url == None %}
            <p>none</p>
        {% else %}
            <p> url is there </p>
        {% endif %}
    </td>
 {% endfor %}
```

I've also changed `item.some_url` to `some_url` too which isn't working. Also, I've tried if `item.some_url` is defined or `some_url` is defined which aren't working.

Can someone please help me out

Comment: Can you check if if `item.facewall_url != None` rather than checking that it's `==None`. Also I see you iterating over `{% for some_url in item.some_url %}`, why not check for `some_url` rather than `item.facewall_url`?

Comment: let me try that.

Comment: Its not working, it is always going to "not none" part regardless if I am matching  == None or != None.

Comment: I see you corrected the some_url, I believe you want to try:` {% if some_url == None %}` rather than `{% if item.some_url == None %}`. [Manual](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for)

Comment: I just renamed facewall to some_url to be consistent. Anyways I will give more try tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% if some_url %} 
   <found logic in html> 
{% else %} 
   <Not found logic in html> 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
{% if items.some_url %}
<display your html>
{% else %}
<display your html>
{% endif %}
```